# Python: 'MultipartEncoder' object is not iterable when trying to send huge file

Tags: python, python-requests

I have problem while trying to send big file via requests.toolbelt in python2.
I need to send to server filename + filedata + mimetype

My upload "command" looks like this:

```
file = MultipartEncoder({'files[]': (filename, filedata, mimetype)})
UploadFile = requests.post(UploadURL, files=file, allow_redirects=False)
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
'MultipartEncoder' object is not iterable
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the `MultpartEncoder()` instance to the `data` keyword argument, not `files`:

```
UploadFile = requests.post(UploadURL, data=file, allow_redirects=False)
```